# How to implement increase key operation in a binary heap

Tags: c, data-structures, heap, implementation, binary-heap

I want to implement a max binary heap in c.
The header that I written:

```
typedef struct max_heap_t *max_heap_ptr;

max_heap_ptr max_heap_create(size_t element_size, size_t key_size, int (*key_compare)(void *a, void *b));
size_t max_heap_get_nitems(max_heap_ptr heap);
void max_heap_insert(max_heap_ptr heap, void *element_ptr, void *key_ptr);
void max_heap_max(max_heap_ptr heap, void *element_ptr);
void max_heap_extract_max(max_heap_ptr heap, void *element_ptr);
void max_heap_increase_key(max_heap_ptr heap, void *element_ptr, void *new_key);
void max_heap_free(max_heap_ptr heap);
```

The heap is implemented using an array.
I don't know how to implement `max_heap_increase_key`. In fact given the pointer to the element, I don't know how to get the index of the element in the heap array in time O (log n). I could use a linear search, but it would take O (n) time. Do I need to use a map? I'd like to avoid this...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't a max binary heap implemented as a binary tree, not an array?

Comment: Is the heap is an array of elements, or an array of pointers to elements?

Comment: @PiRocks You can implement a binary tree using an array. Check [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). The implementation with arrays in this case is more efficient because it does not need to manage pointers.

Comment: @user3386109 array of pointers to elements

Comment: I'm aware you can implement a binary tree with an array as a backing structure, but I'm not sure why you have to use a linear search, since its still a binary tree?

Comment: @PiRocks I'm reading [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) by Thomas H. Cormen and he use arrays. Most implementations I saw on GitHub use an array (but they use simply integers as elements). However this is a binary tree (not a binary search tree). So I can't use search in log n...

Comment: Idk if this helps much but all your elements are allocated in the same array, then you can derive an array index from the element_ptr with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @PiRocks Memory for the element is allocated by the client. The insert operation copies the element pointer to the heap array element. So pointers to elements are not necessarily adjacent.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128372/755